# regex question - if I knew how to ask it proprly i'd properly know the answer as well?

Tags: php, regex

So basically my regex is not working as I expect & I don't know why.

I am working in a fairly regulated environment so this should not be too much of a problem - all the html tags are generated by a script & follow this pattern: only `li`, `p` and `h(3-6)` tags are present. all text is between tags and there are no spaces between tags.

I 'need' to write something to surround the `li`s with `ul` tags. here is what i got:

```
preg_replace('#(<li>[^<p|<h]+</li>)(?!<li>)#', '<ul>$1</ul>', $html)
```

however it only matches the last `li` pair in a set for some reason. Anyone can tell me why ... please?

Comment: What is the `#(` and `)#`? It appears to just be a basic capture surrounded by `#` characters, meaning it will match the string `#<li>something</li>#`. Surely that's not right.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - you don't have to surround your pattern with /. You can use any character instead. And when you have a lot of slashes in your pattern, using a different character like # or | means you don't have to \ escape them which can improve readability a lot.

Comment: @ithcy: `preg_replace` requires surrounding the pattern? That sounds completely useless given that the pattern is, by definition, already a pattern. Still, from the examples in the documentation you appear to be right. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin, no, it's not required, it's just convention. But - what if you need to use pattern modifiers?

Comment: @Andrew I know this is usually the case, but I thought this was because html is complex & you never know exactly how things will be formed, etc. in this case the html really is as simple and constrained as I originally stated. I have nothing against using a DOMdocument. Mostly I was just posting because I wanted to know why my regex didn't work, though.

Comment: @Kevin you can put modifiers like 'i' (case insensitive) after the second delimiter like #pattern#i

Comment: @ithcy: It isn't? I went looking through the PHP documentation on PCRE syntax, and [it claims](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) that the delimiters are required.

Comment: @Kevin Now I'm not sure which side of the question you're on here :) Yes, it is required to use delimiters. I got a little mixed up.

Comment: I guess I'm just used to languages where either the regex is first-class syntax (e.g. just like here, but without the single-quotes), or modifiers are given as extra arguments to the appropriate functions. I find it rather backwards to have a string contain delimiters + modifiers.

Comment: I'm with you on that. I'm sure in PHP's case it's due to the P in PCRE - the syntax seems to have been lifted wholesale from Perl, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^<p|<h]` doesn't do what you expect. It matches a single character that is not any of the characters `<p|h`. If your HTML really is as constrained as you say, and you cannot have an `<li>` nested inside another `<li>`, then the following should work:

```
preg_replace('#(<li>.*?</li>)+#', '<ul>$0</ul>', $html)
```

The sequence `.*?` is just like `.*` except the trailing `?` is the non-greedy modifier. By default `.*` is greedy - it will consume as many characters as it can, then backtrack if the rest of the pattern doesn't match. The non-greedy modifier inverts this. It consumes as few characters as it can and advances if the rest of the pattern cannot match. As the rest of the pattern is simply `</li>`, this effectively captures all text up to, but not including, the first sequence `</li>`. This pattern is then nested inside a capture which is then repeated with `+`, meaning it will match one or more sequences of `<li>` tags.

Comment: @Long Ears: It will wrap a sequence of `<li>` tags with `<ul>`. Multiple distinct sequences of `<li>` tags will be wrapped separately. Note that I used `$0` instead of `$1` in the replacement.

Comment: I think I finally understand greedy vs non-greedy. Super helpful.